# How do I change the alias of python executable in command line?

Tags: python, command-line

Everytime I need to run a python file, I need to enter this into the command line.

```
python3.7 filename.py
```

Is there a way I can change the name from python3.7 to just py or something shorter?

Answer (score 1):

```
alias py=python3.7
py filename.py
```

Add the alias to you `bash_aliases` to get it in every terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you can shorten it to nothing by adding the line

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

to the top of your python file. Then `chmod 755 <filename.py>` and run it like any other executable.

Comment: What's the point in writing chmod 755 everytime? Might as well go with oython 3.7. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: `chmod 755` sets the permissions on the file to make it directly executable, so you'd only do it once. Then you just run the file like `./filename.py` as many times as you want. If it's in a directory that's on your `PATH`, you can run it from anywhere with just `filename.py`.